# Converting Google Doc to PDF using REST API

Tags: rest, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I've written a script in Deluge that sends HTTP requests to Google Drive to make a copy of a Google Doc in a Shared Drive, then edit the text.

My next step is converting that Doc to a PDF, but I'm stuck. I've tried using the Files:update method https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update with:

PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/fileId

to update the mime type to 'application/pdf', but even though I get a successful response, the file stays a Google Doc file.

Has anyone found a way to change Docs into PDFs using without downloading and re-uploading the file?

Comment: As far as i know you cant convert it once it has been uploaded you need to download it and upload it with the change in mime type.

Comment: Effectively, is not possible to transform. Although you don't need to download as per say,  you just need to stream the export result to a resumable upload session. I don't see the big deal honestly. It should be something fairly simple.

Comment: Thanks for the responses,

I was able to use the file.export method to get the PDF version of the file and now I'm working on uploading that back to the same location using file.create